# Arabic letters converted to Latin

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, encoding, localization

I am developing an Arabic application that stores data in SQLite database..
 I insert data as follows

```
mySQLiteAdapter.Insert(" تطبيق عربي");
```

but the problem is that sometimes when I open my Eclipse I find that the Arabic letters have converted to Latin like

```
mySQLiteAdapter.Insert("Êã ÊÏÑíÈå Úáì ßíÝíÉ ãÊÇÈÚÉ");
```

I don't know what is the problem, since I have changed the encoding settings to UTF-8..

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Did you [configure UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4478601/315306)?

Comment: Either the inserting in your app, or the reading of the data in Eclipse uses a wrong encoding. To find out which, show the result of the query `SELECT quote(CAST(MyColumn AS BLOB)) FROM MyTable` for one record.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `"ةعباتم ةيفيك ىلع هبيردت مت"` or `"تم تدريبه على كيفية متابعة"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem from your pc 
Change system change system location

Control Panal >> Language >> date and time format >> change system locale >> Arabic

Comment: My system locale is Arabic ! any other suggestions?

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Workspace -> Text textfile encoding to UTF-8